# Is it offensive and personal to say 'It seems your memory does not serve you right'?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, american-english

Context:

I was debating about a meeting detail with my colleague and I said 'It seems your memory does not serve you right. The details should be...and... rather than ...'

My colleague freaked out and believed 'It seems your memory does not serve you right' offensive and personal. My colleague is not a native speaker and I speculate he did not understand this idiom.

As a non-native English speaker, I was totally lost.

Isn't it the same thing as 'It seems you don't remember the details correctly'? Was it really offensive and personal, from a native English speaker's perspective?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see this as an English Learning question.  More about cultural expectations, and interpersonal skills. The meaning is clear, it is certainly "personal".  I can see how someone might be upset at being told that they are not able to remember something.  I can see how someone might see this as a sarcastic way of saying "you're lying".  But these are functions of the particular person, and not a general point about the English Langauge.  As there is no English learning, I vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, a Canadian, it's a natural and idiomatic way to tell someone you disagree with something they claim to remember, though it sounds a bit antiquated. I found many hits for "*your memory does not serve you*" on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk02sxG05jDPzeYcojQRKlP-mFKjHvw%3A1621851670953&source=hp&ei=Fn6rYKW1N6i3gge3paKIDw&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYKuMJgmRE5-aeeij8dbUjTPUCApsHQHl&q=%22your%20memory%20does%20not%20serve%20you%22), and of the few I looked at, none appeared offensive.

A slightly more common form is:

> It seems your memory **is not serving** you **well**.

It's a bit cheeky, so I wouldn't use it in a formal situation, but I wouldn't think of it as rude or offensive. A non-native speaker might interpret it to mean, "There's something wrong with your brain", but that's not the intent.

I think cultural differences are at play here too. Like, in Canada, people call each other "crazy" all the time, but it's usually rude to call someone a "fool". Compare this to Korea, where you hear the word "fool" (바보) daily, and "crazy" (미친) is a serious insult. So it's well possible that questioning someone's memory -- especially at work -- could be a grave insult to your co-worker, whereas to you it's just a figure of speech.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was really not commenting on his memory. I googled it too and I didn't understand why he considered it as offensive. But I do think he interpreted as "There's something wrong with your brain". 

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: @HaloLaunch Happy to help! If you like Jeffrey's answer or mine, consider upvoting them, and eventually giving one of the answers a checkmark if you're satisfied with an answer. The "reputation" points users get from upvotes and checkmarks is the currency that keeps users motivated to contribute. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking about a cultural value rather than something embedded in the language itself. It is true that speakers of a common language often share similar cultural values, but I would not rely on that in all circumstances.

As an American, I will say that your first remark would be inappropriate in most business settings. As you notice, it is very personal. More than that, it suggests a permanent impairment rather than a one-time error. It's quite an insult.

But even your revised version seems too personal. I would consider someone else's memory off-limits for the purpose of this discussion—and irrelevant. It doesn't matter why someone made an error. And there is the possibility that you are in error as well.

I'll add that I am assuming a confrontation among colleagues who are not friends. As intimacy grows, we take more liberties. With a close colleague whom I was accustomed to joking with, I might go quite farther and say something like, "You must have forgotten to take your meds that day."

With a colleague you are not friends with, I suggest either of the following:

> I remember the discussion differently.
> I am confident that if minutes had been taken, they would match the way I remember the discussion.

But I am getting into advice-column territory here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

The point is that I did not mean to comment on his memory at all! That conversation has nothing to do with "memory". I thought it's just an idiom, saying that you might be mistaken on some details.

Comment: I tried to click the upvote button but it seems I can only upvote when I have 15 reputation points which I don't have now as a new user. I wish I could upvote all of your answers. Really appreciate you sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Thanks for the kind thought. If my colleagues consider it valuable, they will let me know. ;)

Comment: The OP only needs one more upvote on this question to get voting privileges. JUST SAYIN... @JeffreyCarney  :)